# What is the criteria for the "select your next badge" section?

Tags: discussion, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

I was looking for my unearned badges, and saw the `pundit` badge, so I look in the *select your next badge* section to look how many comment I have righ now with more than 5 upvotes (as this section tells you your progress) and I realized that the badge wasn't in that list, so I wonder why? How are the badges for the *select your next badge* selected?

Comment: On meta, it seems to be: Choose "informed", [which is unobtainable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253486).

Comment: This is a complete guess, but I would assume it has to do with the tracking of some of the badge criteria. If they're only checking say, once a day, then putting it on the profile next badge would be really misleading.